# probability generating function moments for the multivariate case

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose ${\bf X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_d)$ is a non-negative integer-valued random vector, with pmf $p$, I tried to extend the results of the univariate generating function to the multivariate case, is the following correct?

$$\left. \frac{\partial^{k_1 + \cdots + k_d}}{\partial z_1^{k_1} \cdots \partial 
z_d^{k_d}} \right|_{{\bf z} = 0} = k_1 ! \cdots k_n !p (k_1, \ldots,
k_d)$$

For $X_j \in L^j$, $$\left. \frac{\partial^{k_1 + \cdots +
k_d}}{\partial z_1^{k_1} \cdots \partial z_d^{k_d}} \right|_{{\bf z} =
1^-} =\mathbf{E} [X_1 (X_1 - 1) \cdots (X_1 - k_1 + 1) \cdots X_d (X_d - 1)
\cdots (X_d - k_d + 1)]$$